Microsoft Office 2021 uninstall error "We're sorry, Something went wrong"
We have installed Office 2021 and we want to upgrade to Office 2024. Unfortunately the install Process won't uninstall Office 21 first, it just crashes with the Error that we need to uninstall Office 21 first.
So lets do it the official MS way (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/administration/assistant-office-uninstall) so I downloaded the latest SaRAcmd.exe. But that fails with the wonderful error message:

We're sorry, something went wrong.
Scenario finished with exit code: [1]

Even adding the option -LogFolder won't generate any output in the logfolder. And Google give only 3 (in words: Three) results.
Now i don't know what to do.
The Click-to-Run service is running. Installed is Office 21 LTSC Professional Plus Version 2107 (Build 14332.20771) from a network drive. At least this version is on my Test-Machine. Updates also comes from the same network drive.

Have you tried running the Office Uninstallation Tool?

That one is a GUI-Tool, so not usable on about 800 Computers. Uninstalling by hand works, but not using the SaRACmd-Tool. Now something new: I tried it on another computer give the Error Message "68: We could not find any Office Version". And there is certainly an Office 2021 installed. That Sara-Tool is totally garbage.

I just tried the that GUI Tool, that one also reports that there is no Office installed. But it certainly is installed.

Other tests: Same on Windows 11 and Office 21. On a Computer running Office 16 the SaRA-Tool works. So it must be something with Office 21.

I found the solution. Problem is, SaRA is somehow not compatible with an XML-installed Office 2021.
Solution. Create XML-File:
<Configuration>
<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="True" />
<Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="True" />
<Remove>
<Product ID="ProPlus2021Volume">
</Product>
</Remove>
</Configuration>

Run it: setup.exe /configure [XML-File] or better put that in a batchfile and run it.
Source:
https://www.urtech.ca/2019/03/solved-command-line-to-uninstall-office365-pro-plus/
